# How to get Exact page position from viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

It is confusing when I print the current position from ViewPager. I searched it and get a solution from stackoverflow. But I want to know is it possible to get the exact layout  position continuously from viewpager when page is changed. Actually I want to get the current position in instantiateItem method. Is it possible. Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // using the position parameter, inflate the proper layout, also add
        // it to the container parameter
        ViewGroup pageView = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(
                mLayouts[position], container, false);

        container.addView(pageView);
        return pageView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try pageView.getCurrentItem();